# svn checkout to /tmp in cygwin, but it checkout to c:/tmp

Tags: bash, svn

I use **CYGWIN** as my main shell.
I wrote a script(BASH) to checkout my project, and proceed some build tests.
I had confirmed that I don't assign the wrong path, **it is "/tmp" exactly**.
My system is windows 7-64bits. In my own PC, my script works well. But when it is used on someone's windows 7(64bits), it checkouts the same repository to "**c:/tmp**" instead.

Can anyone show me any hints?

edit:
If anyone would like to check my script, I'm glad to show them:

```
#!/bin/bash

function build_project() {
    rtn="fail"
    cmd /c cocos compile -p android -j4
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        rtn="ok"
    fi
    eval "$1=${rtn}"
}

tmp_dir=/tmp
checkout_dir=${tmp_dir}/cocos_igs
rm -rf ${checkout_dir}
svn co http://10.1.254.53/svn/cocos_igs/trunk ${checkout_dir}
cocos_root=${checkout_dir}/cocos2d-x

cd ${cocos_root}/tests/cpp-empty-test
build_project result
if [ "${result}" == "fail" ]; then
    exit 1
fi

cd ${cocos_root}/tests/cpp-tests
build_project result
if [ "${result}" == "fail" ]; then
    exit 1
fi

new_project=new_project
cocos_project=${tmp_dir}/${new_project}
rm -rf ${cocos_project}

cd ${tmp_dir}
cmd /c cocos new ${new_project} -p igs.rd3.rebuild_test -l cpp -d .
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    exit 1
fi

cd ${cocos_project}
build_project result
if [ "${result}" == "fail" ]; then
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Please include the exact copy-and-pasted checkout command in your question. Is the other person also  using Cygwin?

Comment: Also, are you positive, you are using it from cygwin shell & not cmd.exe?
is the `svn` binary compiled for `cygwin`, or is it windows binary?